# I am unable to render Math in docusaurus

Tags: markdown, docusaurus, katex

Reading the documentation, I have followed all the steps. With my `docusaurus.config.js` files here.

```js
// @ts-check
// Note: type annotations allow type checking and IDEs autocompletion

const lightCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/github');
const darkCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/dracula');
const math = require('remark-math');
const katex = require('rehype-katex');

/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
const config = {
  title: 'My Site',
  tagline: 'Dinosaurs are cool',
  url: 'https://your-docusaurus-test-site.com',
  baseUrl: '/',
  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',
  organizationName: 'facebook', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'docusaurus', // Usually your repo name.

  presets: [
    ['@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          remarkPlugins: [math],
          rehypePlugins: [katex],
          showLastUpdateTime: true
        },
        blog: false,
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  stylesheets: [
    {
      href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.13.24/dist/katex.min.css',
      type: 'text/css',
      integrity:
        'sha384-odtC+0UGzzFL/6PNoE8rX/SPcQDXBJ+uRepguP4QkPCm2LBxH3FA3y+fKSiJ+AmM',
      crossorigin: 'anonymous',
    },
  ],
  themeConfig:
  {
    navbar: {
      title: 'My Site',
      logo: {
        alt: 'My Site Logo',
        src: 'img/logo.svg',
      },
      items: [
        {
          type: 'doc',
          docId: 'intro',
          position: 'left',
          label: 'Tutorial',
        },
        {to: '/blog', label: 'Blog', position: 'left'},
        {
          href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
          label: 'GitHub',
          position: 'right',
        },
      ],
    },
    footer: {
      style: 'dark',
      links: [
        {
          title: 'Docs',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Tutorial',
              to: '/docs/intro',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'Community',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Stack Overflow',
              href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusaurus',
            },
            {
              label: 'Discord',
              href: 'https://discordapp.com/invite/docusaurus',
            },
            {
              label: 'Twitter',
              href: 'https://twitter.com/docusaurus',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: 'More',
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Blog',
              to: '/blog',
            },
            {
              label: 'GitHub',
              href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      copyright: `Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()} My Project, Inc. Built with Docusaurus.`,
    },
    prism: {
      theme: lightCodeTheme,
      darkTheme: darkCodeTheme,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

I have installed `remark-math` and `rehype-katex` however the code is not compiled. Here is my `index.md` file

```
## HEllo

Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\R$ be Riemann integrable. Let $F\colon[a,b]\to\R$ be
$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$. Then $F$ is continuous, and at all $x$ such that
$f$ is continuous at $x$, $F$ is differentiable at $x$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$.

$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x)\,dx
$$
```

To get some more information, I run up the server in my localhost and I tried to inspect the elements over there. I found that the stylesheet is loaded correctly but somehow the $ signs are not rendered correctly as it is provided by the `remark-math` plugin.

On inspecting the HTML for the math I found it's rendered as

```
<p>$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x)\,dx
$$</p>
```

What am I missing in the whole process?

Comment: Have you added the imports? Like `import remarkMath from 'remark-math'`  ? And the file extension must be `mdx` not `md`.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a compile error like this when following the official document.

> ValidationError: "remarkPlugins[1]" does not look like a valid MDX plugin config. A plugin config entry should be one of:
>
> - A tuple, like `[require("rehype-katex"), { strict: false }]`, or
> - A simple module, like `require("remark-math")`

you can change your config like this.

```
remarkPlugins: [math,{strict:false}]
```

Another point is do not put your equation in code block.

Solution reference: [link](https://linlan.xyz/docs/docusaurus/basic-config#33-%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F)